# Can we distinguish Blackberry is in USB mode or charge mode?

Tags: java, blackberry, usb, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am new to blackberry-7. In my application when I plug my phone into the cable (by means of the USB cable) I want to find if my blackberry connected with USB is in charging mode or transfer mode. How is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB can be detected asynchronously using [`SystemListener2`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/SystemListener2.html) and also synchronously using [`DeviceInfo.getBatteryStatus`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html#getBatteryStatus%28%29).

For what you need the battery status won't work because it probably charges in both normal and transfer modes, and then there's the problem of detecting the cable when the battery is full. So I'd try registering a `SystemListener2` instance and hopefully the callback `usbConnectionStateChange` will be passed the flag [SystemListener2.USB_STATE_CABLE_CONNECTED](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/SystemListener2.html#USB_STATE_CABLE_CONNECTED)  as argument. When it is transferring, I'd expect the flags [USB_STATE_ENUMERATED](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/SystemListener2.html#USB_STATE_ENUMERATED) and [USB_STATE_MS_INTERFACE_ENUMERATED](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/SystemListener2.html#USB_STATE_MTP_INTERFACE_ENUMERATED) to be received in the callback as well, but I've never tested it on a real device.

And I don't know what would happen if the device is already connected when the listener is registered.

To register the listener, call

```
    Application.getApplication().addSystemListener(mySysListener2);
```